# How to map the wso2 development structure

Tags: wso2

For integrating new module and developing wso2 emm such as selective wipe,backup data.
need information about architecture of wso2 emm.as developer what are thing he/she should know for developing wso2 emm new module.

Answer (score 0):

You better look at the source code of [WSO2 EMM here](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/tree/master/modules/apps/emm).

Comment: Thanks @Dilshan,...Actually we are looking to develop new modules like selective wipe for the EMM...  I have gone through the jag and JS...but am not able to start off the blocks. Pls let me know how to go about implementing this feature...Also do let me know what features are planned in EMM v2.0 release

Comment: Implementation differs based on the platform whether its iOS or Android. If Android you better look at Android agent source code as well. Featurewise its not decided what to be added in 2.0 version yet.

Comment: Thanks,How to import wso2 emm source code in developer studio ...i cant do.

Comment: Its a maven project and you should be able to get that imported even in Eclipse if you have installed maven plugins on it.